# FTP Transfers Slow Between 2 Servers

Tags: ftp, latency, traffic-shaping, slow-connection, network-speed

Between 2 dedicated servers, hosted in 2 different DCs (different companies), the FTP upload speeds are always much slower than the max connection speed.
Specs:
Windows 2008 on both.
Quad core/8 GB RAM/1 Gbit network care
FileZilla FTP Server

- Both have 100mbps connections
- Speed maxes out at about 30 mbps
- Ping shows 30 ms of latency
- Tried multiple transfer threads- it helped increase speeds a little but never past 30 mbps.
- Tested an HTTP transfer on the client server from the **same** host server while FTP was running- it transferred at 12 mbps! (1.5 MBytes/S).. and did not affect FTP speeds- FTP speeds stayed constant. That is, total server speed was 42 mbps while transferring over HTTP and FTP. So it seems the connection between the 2 isn't being fully used.
- For the **client** server, I tried connecting to different FTP servers and seeing if I got different transfers. It was always slow with FTP- around 400 kBytes/s with 3 streams.
- For the **host** server, I tried other FTP connections and they were better but still not as great as the HTTP transfer.

Side note- I've noticed this "slower FTP than HTTP effect" a lot after speaking to some users across all 3 data centers I've ever used- Users say FTP speeds are never as fast as HTTP download. But sometimes I think it's something about my configuration.

Here are some possibilities, but maybe it's something else:
1. Is it possible that there is traffic shaping going on? I read this:
http://oreilly.com/catalog/bgp/chapter/ch06.html
It seems to suggest that protocols like HTTP are going to get priority and FTP, which is latency-friendly, is going to get the back seat. But I'm using DCs- not personal Internet connections.

2. Is there something I can do with my TCP window size? I tried adjusting it on FileZilla Server to make it larger or smaller... I tried every value and it never let me break the 30mbps barrier.

Let me know your thoughts. Here is a tracert, with some names hidden.
Tracing route to ******************
over a maximum of 30 hops:

1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  ********************

2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  ********************

3     6 ms     6 ms     6 ms  ********************

4     7 ms     6 ms     6 ms  66.208.216.85

5    11 ms    11 ms     7 ms  be-12-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.84.189]

6     8 ms     7 ms     7 ms  pos-1-6-0-0-pe01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net [68.86.87.130]

7     6 ms     6 ms     7 ms  te0-3-0-17.ccr21.ord03.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.11.253]

8     7 ms     7 ms     7 ms  be2006.mpd21.ord01.atlas.cogentco.com [154.54.5.17]

9    32 ms    32 ms     *     *************.atlas.cogentco.com

10    42 ms   100 ms    33 ms  *************.atlas.cogentco.com

11    32 ms    32 ms    31 ms  ********************

12    32 ms    32 ms    31 ms  [******DESTINATION*****]

Trace complete.

Comment: How are the two servers connected? Over the internet? Or via a private link between the two datacentres?

Comment: Over the Internet. No private link.

Comment: did you ever find out why?

Comment: Aside from the possible causes I mentioned, I never determined the exact cause.